# session[:user_id] initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I need to control if the user is currently logged in my web site, but I have a problem to initialize the variable that I used for this control: `session[:user_id]`.

This is the code that I used:

```
def authenticate_user
    if session[:user_id].nil?
      redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'index')
      return false
    else
      # set current_user by the current user object
      @current_user = User.find session[:user_id]
      return true
    end
 end
```

I call this method in all controllers that I want block to not logged users, with this code:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:index,:show,:edit]
```

In my opinion the problem is the `session[:user_id]` variable, when the user visits my web site the variable doesn't initialize to `nil` so the control not work.

I can initialize the variable in the controller of the index page but this method is wrong.

Example, when i request this page without login:

> 127.0.0.1:3000/menus

the error is:

> ```
> undefined local variable or method `authenticate_user' for #<MenusController:0x007faa6e5a4c20>
> ```

**UPDATE:**

Now the error is no more but when the users have not logged in 
The condition:

```
if session[:user_id].nil?
```

is not verified.

If i declare this method in the users controller:

```
before_filter :initializes



def initializes
    session[:user_id]=nil;
  end
```

it works! 
Also if the users does not require the 'index page (the login page)' but I do not understand why

Comment: Your unless statement should probably be an if. At the moment the logic is "if there IS a user id, redirect to users/index. If there IS NOT a user id, find a user using the non existent id"

Comment: ah ok! I have to replace 'Unless' with an 'if' .am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
 renturn unless session[:user_id]
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end


def authenticate_user!
  redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'index') unless current_user
end
```

And the action index should not force login because we are redirecting there unless the user is not logged in.

In your users_controller.rb

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show,:edit]
```

Answer (score 0):

you defined authenticate_use but you have authenticate_user in your filter call

Comment: ok! Now the error is no more but when the users have not logged in

The condition:
 if session[:user_id].nil? 
is not verified.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Devise gem for authentication https://github.com/plataformatec/devise